# What SDK version to download?

Tags: windows-7, sdk, windows-7-x64

I need to install Win7 SDK on Win7 amd64 computer. Microsoft download page http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18950 contains 3 iso files: GRMSDK_EN_DVD.iso, GRMSDKIAI_EN_DVD.iso and GRMSDKX_EN_DVD.iso. I wasted a few hours downloading first one, and, of course, got an error message "WinSDK_amd64.msi not found", which means: I need another ISO.

So, which one of these two: GRMSDKIAI_EN_DVD.iso or GRMSDKX_EN_DVD.iso matches my Win7 64 bit computer?

Comment: Expand the Install Instructions section on that page.  You'll see that EN is for x86, X_EN is for x64, IAI_EN is for Itanium.

Comment: @HansPassant it's given for granted the fact that a mere mortal just reads what's in front of the eyes, Microsoft is not making things predictable by hiding the content. Thank you for your help.

Comment: New Download link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8442

Answer (score 75):

Here are the descriptions of the three versions. (FROM MSDN)

- GRMSDK_EN_DVD.iso is a version for x86 environment.
- GRMSDKX_EN_DVD.iso is a version for x64 environment.
- GRMSDKIAI_EN_DVD.iso is a version for Itanium environment.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 7):

You need to download the first one "GRMSDKX_EN_DVD.iso". This one is for an AMD64. If this doesn't work you need to get it from some were else.