# installing net framework 4 upon windows 10 environment

Tags: .net, matlab, installation, windows-10

i really need to install .net 4 for MATLAB R2016a compiler, the problem s windows 10 has .net 4.6 and don't allow any earlier version to be installed
 I followed the suggestions in [a previous related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35733040/how-to-install-net-4-framework-in-windows-10) but unfortunatelly none of the mentioned packages installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

having .NET 4.6 installed (it's part of Windows 10 so you need not manually install it) means you have .NET 4.0, 4.5, 4.5.1, 4.5.2 and 4.6 installed and can run code targeting any of those framework versions without making any modifications to your Windows installation.

You **cannot** install .NET 4.0 when you have a later version installed as each version is an in-place update to the last.

Update: In my experience with SDK 7.1 and installing the required C compiler for Matlab on Windows 10, you can install SDK 7.1 from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279

However, it fails to detect .NET framework 4. As a result you cannot install the required C++ compilers. You can download these manually at the following link: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4422

Now Matlab was able to set SDK 7.1 as C compiler. Hope it works for you as well

Comment: but every time i tried to install SDK 7.1 compiler for matlab, the system prevent it from installing and asks for .net framework 4

Answer (score 1):

Turn ON windows features of .net framework 3.5 and .net framework 4.6 from Control Panel >> Programs and Features.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh506443(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I did it but nothing new happened, the same error message and again I can't select the compiler to be installed