# "Error writing to file" during SDK 7.1 Installation on Windows 10

Tags: c++, .net, sdk, installation, windows-10

I am trying to install SDK 7.1 on Windows 10. This seems to be a thorny task for many people, I have tried the following solutions:

- [Answer #1 to "Cannot install Windows SDK 7.1 on Windows 10"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32534158/2661491)
- [Answer #2 to "Cannot install Windows SDK 7.1 on Windows 10"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32322920/2661491)
- [Why does the SDK 7.1 installation fail with an "Installation Failed" message on my Windows system?](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95039-why-does-the-sdk-7-1-installation-fail-with-an-installation-failed-message-on-my-windows-system)

In every case I get one of the following errors:

> Error 1304. Error writing to file: Microsoft.Build.CPPTasks.Common.dll. Verify that you have access to that directory.

or

> Error 1304. Error writing to file: mscorcfg.dll.  Verify that you have access to that directory.

I am running the installer with admin privileges and I have verified that my .NET installation is working (using the [.NET Setup Verification Tool](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/astebner/2008/10/13/net-framework-setup-verification-tool-users-guide/)).

I have also tried disabling all AV and Firewalls and even tried a [clean boot](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929135) but all of these steps led to the same error.

**Edit:**

I have also tried installing Visual Studio [2015, 2013, 2012] and they all fail with a `Error writing to file: ****.dll` error.