# No supported SDK compiler found on this computer/LIBSVM

Tags: matlab, libsvm

I try to install LIBSVM on a Windows 10 PC. Everytime I try to run the make file I get the following error:

> No supported SDK or compiler was found on this computer. 
>   For a list of supported compilers, see
>   http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers/R2013b/win64.html

I have tried to install all supported compilers and non of them worked and I stil get the error message back. Also when I type mex -setup it says:"No supported SDK or compiler was found on this computer. "

I have read this question and several others: https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100144-why-does-mex-not-find-the-microsoft-windows-sdk-7-1-installed-on-64-bit-windows-in-matlab-7-14-r201 and also tried to isntall the respective batch but as I said I am using Windows 10 not 7 and it gives me the respective error message. Moreover I have installed not only the compiler but also the .NET Framework 4. I have also installed the dependency walker and it does not show me any missing packages.

As you can possibly see from the question I am not an expert but I am searching for hours now and I get back the same error message again and again.Are there any suggestions how I could make LIBSVM work?

Thanks

Carlos

Answer (score 0):

[Cannot install Windows SDK 7.1 on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32091593/cannot-install-windows-sdk-7-1-on-windows-10)

That did the trick--in case anyone ever stumbles upon the same problem.