# GraalVM for Windows

Tags: windows, graalvm, quarkus

I'm testing the new RedHat framwork [Quarkus](https://quarkus.io). I'm trying to built a native executable and to this I need to download [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org), but on [GraalVM's download page](https://www.graalvm.org/downloads/) there are two Editions (community and entreprise) which are available only on Mac and Linux, but not for Windows.

Is there an alternative to download GraalVm for Windows?

Comment: Maybe you can look here : https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/oracle-labs/program-languages/downloads/index.html

Comment: **Windows GraalVM Preview**: _Support for GraalVM on Windows is currently under development. Until it is available, a preview build is provided below that includes the Graal compiler but does not include support for building native images or installing guest languages._

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently (2019-04-01) there's no full GraalVM distribution for Windows. One can get the preview version for Windows from the [OTN GraalVM page](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/oracle-labs/program-languages/downloads/index.html) which includes the Graal compiler. However, the `native-image` functionality, being OS specific, doesn't work very well on Windows yet. The GraalVM team is actively working on it and you can follow the progress on GitHub -- https://github.com/oracle/graal.

I've heard that WLS works with the linux version or one can try building in a container or a virtual machine. Which is not ideal, but can serve as a workaround until things work.

Answer (score 7):

https://github.com/oracle/graal/releases/tag/vm-19.0.0 introduces Early Adopter Windows Support

It's the first release with Windows support so don't assume same experience as with Linux or macOS distros. Some issues for example - https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/1255 / https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/1258 / https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/1241

If you want to try Windows + native-image combo, be sure you have installed Windows SDK for Windows 7 (not the one for Windows 10!) and running native-image command from Windows SDK 7.1 Command Prompt. You may need to edit some registry entries (see the second and third link below).
More details on GH issues and here on SO:
- https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/1258#issuecomment-491325870
- https://github.com/oracle/graal/issues/1258#issuecomment-492148559
- [Cannot install Windows SDK 7.1 on Windows 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32091593/cannot-install-windows-sdk-7-1-on-windows-10/32322920#32322920)

On Quarkus side there is an initial work for Windows done via https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/pull/2395
Quarkus team is working on changes to properly support GraalVM 19.0.